# Navbar color change after defined y position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a nice navbar that is fixed to the top of the window. When a user scrolls past a certain div, it will change the background color of the navbar. Up to this point, it has been working great for me.

I recently added a few anchor links to my website. Now when a user clicks on an anchor link and is brought to the page with the navbar on it, the navbar is not the correct color. It is only when the user scrolls a little, that the navbar changes color. But I would like the navbar to have the correct background color as soon as the user lands on the page.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var mainbottom = $('.changenavcolor').offset().top + $('.changenavcolor').height();

  // on scroll, 
  $(window).on('scroll',function(){

  // we round here to reduce a little workload
  stop = Math.round($(window).scrollTop());
  if (stop > mainbottom) {
      $('.os .navbar').addClass('navbarblue');
  } else {
      $('.os .navbar').removeClass('navbarblue');
  }

  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<header class="top-page-header">
<div class="page-overlay">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="changenavcolor"></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
```

I think what I am looking for is something that changes the color of the nav after a certain y coordinate. Like after y=100 change nav color. I could be wrong, but I am thinking this would solve the problem.

Comment: added html to original question.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a function to your links, for example using `a.anchorlink` as selector, or simply `$('a')` if you want to target every link:

```
$('a.anchorlink').click(function () {
  $('.os .navbar').addClass('navbarblue');
});
```

Or you could check if there is a #hash on page load in your URL if you want to:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  // Hash exists, fire function, for example
  // $('.os .navbar').addClass('navbarblue');
} else {
  // Hash doesn't exist, fire function, for example
  // $('.os .navbar').removeClass('navbarblue');
}
```

Comment: This is not going to work because the navbar will always stay the same color on pages with a hash. I would like the page to behave just like the original page meaning the nav would change color when the user scrolls past the "changenavcolor" div.